# Save line by line buffer in mongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a server written in nodejs which receives a file through `server.on('connection', function(conn) {` which stores that data on the buffer.

This data is a log file where each line has 3 important columns:

time - source file - message

E.g.:

```
2014-02-05 22:12:33,268 - test.py:__init__() - This is message
2014-02-05 22:12:33,268 - test.py:__init__() - This is message 2
```

I would like to store this data on a mongoDB system breaking the log file received in lines and those lines into columns. I have in mind using the client IP as key.

Right now I'm creating files where I put the hole data because I don't know how to read line by line on data stored this way, as readline module is just for files.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Here's the little code of my server:

```
var net = require('net'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    buffer = require('buffer');


var server = net.createServer(function(conn) {
    console.log('server connected');

});

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = '9001';
var DEST_DIR = './logs';

server.listen(PORT, HOST, function() {
    // Check if DEST_DIR exists
    if (!fs.existsSync(DEST_DIR)) {
        console.log(DEST_DIR + ' not found. Creating it now...');
        fs.mkdir('logs', '700');
    }
    //listening
    console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT + '\n');

    server.on('connection', function(conn) {
        var current_time = Date.now();

        console.log('connection made...\n')
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('data received');
            console.log('data is: \n' + data);
            // Create file
            fs.writeFile(DEST_DIR + '/' + current_time + '.txt', data, function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log("File saved");
                }
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: I don't see any code related to MongoDB. So, it's not clear what you're trying to get help with.

Comment: I can figure it out that later, but I want to prepare the buffer to be read line by line and break it in columns each line. Thanks

Comment: What are you using the separate the columns? Post a sample data entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the data on the newline character `\n`. For each entry, split the columns, add each column as a property of an object, and then store the object in mongoDB.

```
data = "time / source file / message \n time / source file / message";
var item, format = ['time', 'source', 'message'];

data = data.toString().split('\n');
while(item = data.pop()){
    item = item.split(/\W-\W/);
    var obj = {};
    item.forEach(function(v, i){
        obj[format[i]] = v;
    });
    // save the object to db
}
```

Comment: A line would be like '2014-02-05 22:12:33,268 - test.py:__init__() - This is message' (separated by the - each column). With your example and how data is saved in my code I get: `TypeError: Object 2014-02-05 22:12:33,268 - test.py:__init__() - This is message has no method 'split' `

Comment: The file is sent complete, so data has several lines of the log file with the format I told you

Comment: Sounds like `data` is a buffer, not a string. I updated the code to handle this

Comment: Also, the columns need to be split using a regexp, to exclude the `-` inside your date.